# how does ggplot scale_continuous work combined with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that looks like this (there is actually much more of it):

```
size program group percent
1    prog1   1     50
2    prog1   1     0.1
1    prog1   2     75
2    prog1   2     1 
1    prog2   1     55
2    prog2   1     2
1    prog2   2     70
2    prog2   2     4
```

I want to plot this using something like this:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(tbl, aes(size, percent, group=group, color=group))+
         geom_point()+
         stat_summary(fun.y=gm_mean, geom='line')+
         scale_x_continuous(trans=log2_trans())+
         scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans())

gm_mean <- function(x) {
 exp(mean(log(x)))
```

}

If I try to run this I get this warning:
In loop_apply(n, do.ply) : NaNs produced
I printed out the values I'm getting in gm_mean and I see they are not the actual values I expect, but they look like the log2 of those values. (The 0.1 turns into -3.3, which then results in NaN from `log()` I think)
Does this mean that using fun.y=mean would actually calculate the geometric mean when using scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans())?
If not how would you go about getting the geometric mean, and if so, how would you go about getting the actual mean with a log scale if I needed it?

What I'm trying to do is make a sort of scatter plot and then draw 2 geometric mean lines (one for each group), but on a log2 scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that using fun.y=mean would actually calculate the geometric mean when using scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans())?

Yes, I think it does mean that.  Here's some examples with trial data:

```
#packages
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

#gm_mean function:
gm_mean <- function(x){exp(mean(log(x)))}

#trial data
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:5, size=100, replace=T), 
                 group=factor(sample(c(1,2,3), size=100, replace=T)))

df$y <- df$x*as.numeric(as.character(df$group))+rnorm(100)+1

#create one outlier for easier visual differences between geomean and arithmean
df[df$x==1&df$group==1,][1,'y'] <- 30

#create base plots
d <- qplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, group=group, color=group) + theme_bw()
d2 <- d + scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans()) +
          scale_x_continuous(trans=log2_trans())

#comparing different plots
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line') + labs(title='untransformed arithmean')
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d + stat_summary(fun.y=gm_mean, geom='line') + labs(title='untransformed geomean')
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d2 + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line') + labs(title='transformed arithmean')
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d2 + stat_summary(fun.y=gm_mean, geom='line') + labs(title='transformed geomean')
```

Observations:

1. On the transformed plot with arithmetic mean, the line for group 1 is identical to the line for the untransformed plot with the geometric mean.  ***Thus, you are right.***
2. To the contrary, the same line on the untransformed plot with arithmetic mean is much more distorted by the artificial outlier.
3. The same lines on the plot transformed with geometric mean are meaningless and lots of NaN problems are encountered.  You should not use geometic means with log-transformed axes.

One further idea: are you sure you want `stat_summary()` instead of `stat_smooth()`?  Your data only has two points in the x axis so I can't be sure, but to my eye and with the example data, these plots are more informative:

```
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d2 + stat_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~x, se=F) + 
     labs(title='stat_smooth transformed')
quartz(width=4, height=4)
d + stat_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~I(2^log(x,2)), se=F) + 
     labs(title='stat_smooth untransformed')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My actual data had 6 points on the x and y axis.
The reason I used `stat_summary` is because mean, and geometric mean were easy for me to explain in the paper. I'll look into `stat_smooth` and maybe use it.